# How do I locate a web element in a dynamic full calendar?

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, fullcalendar, double-click

My Selenium setup is Java/Eclipse/TestNG and my driver is Chrome.

I want to locate a day in a fullcalendar on our webpage and doubleclick it, which in turn would open up a separate panel to create a shift on that day.

My problem is that when I use xpath (retrieved with XPath Helper plugin for Chrome) to locate a certain day in a full calendar, and then try to doubleclick it, nothing happens. I've tried xpaths on other elements on the page and they work. I've also tried the doubleclick method separately on an external test url, and it works. I have a sleep method to make sure the page loads. According to my dev colleague, the full calendar is dynamic.

So the problem must be that xpath can't locate the specific day in the calendar. Does anyone know how to get around this? Is there something wrong with the xpath locator? Here's my code:

```
@Test
public void Userstory1() {
    //Navigate to url and double-click on Monday on row 3 in calendar
    driver.navigate().to(”company/url”);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }

    WebElement element = driver.findElement
            (By.xpath("/html/body/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='main-container']/div[@id='single-column-row']/div"
                    + "[@id='main-content']/div[@id='schedule-container']/div[@id='js-company-schedule-wrapper']/div"
                    + "[@id='js-company-schedule-calendar']/div[@class='fc-view-container']/div[@class='fc-view fc-month-view fc-basic-view']"
                    + "/table/tbody[@class='fc-body']/tr/td[@class='fc-widget-content']/div[@class='fc-day-grid-container']/div"
                    + "[@class='fc-day-grid']/div[@class='fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content'][3]/div[@class='fc-content-skeleton']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]"));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver).doubleClick(element);
    action.build().perform();
}
```

HTML code of calendar part (sorry about the bad format, I dont know how to make it appear better):

```html
<div id="js-company-schedule-calendar" class="fc fc-ltr fc-unthemed"><div class="fc-view-container"><div class="fc-view fc-month-view fc-basic-view"><table><thead class="fc-head"><tr><td class="fc-widget-header"><div class="fc-row fc-widget-header"><table><thead><tr><th class="fc-week-number fc-widget-header" style="width: 18px;"><span>v.</span></th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-mon">måndag</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-tue">tisdag</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-wed">onsdag</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-thu">torsdag</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-fri">fredag</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sat">lördag</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sun">söndag</th></tr></thead></table></div></td></tr></thead><tbody class="fc-body"><tr><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="fc-day-grid-container"><div class="fc-day-grid"><div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content"><div class="fc-bg"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-week-number fc-widget-content" style="width: 18px;"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2016-04-25"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2016-04-26"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2016-04-27"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2016-04-28"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2016-04-29"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2016-04-30"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-past" data-date="2016-05-01"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><thead><tr><td class="fc-week-number" style="width: 18px;"><span>17</span></td><td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2016-04-25">25</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2016-04-26">26</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2016-04-27">27</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2016-04-28">28</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2016-04-29">29</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2016-04-30">30</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-past red-day" data-date="2016-05-01">1</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="fc-week-number" style="width:18px"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content"><div class="fc-bg"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-week-number fc-widget-content" style="width: 18px;"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2016-05-02"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2016-05-03"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2016-05-04"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-past" data-date="2016-05-05"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-past" data-date="2016-05-06"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-past" data-date="2016-05-07"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-past" data-date="2016-05-08"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><thead><tr><td class="fc-week-number" style="width: 18px;"><span>18</span></td><td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2016-05-02">2</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2016-05-03">3</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2016-05-04">4</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-past red-day" data-date="2016-05-05">5</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-past" data-date="2016-05-06">6</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-past" data-date="2016-05-07">7</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-past red-day" data-date="2016-05-08">8</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="fc-week-number" style="width:18px"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class="fc-event-container"><a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable shiftid_525_1 choose"><div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">10:00 - 22:00</span> <span class="fc-title">&nbsp;</span></div><div class="fc-content">
    Obemannat
</div>
<div class="fc-content">
    
    

    

    

    

    

    
</div></a></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content"><div class="fc-bg"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-week-number fc-widget-content" style="width: 18px;"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2016-05-09"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-today fc-state-highlight" data-date="2016-05-10"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2016-05-11"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2016-05-12"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2016-05-13"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2016-05-14"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2016-05-15"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><thead><tr><td class="fc-week-number" style="width: 18px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span>19</span></td><td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2016-05-09">9</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-today fc-state-highlight" data-date="2016-05-10">Idag 10</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2016-05-11">11</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2016-05-12">12</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2016-05-13">13</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2016-05-14">14</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-future red-day" data-date="2016-05-15">15</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="fc-week-number" style="width:18px"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content"><div class="fc-bg"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-week-number fc-widget-content" style="width: 18px;"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2016-05-16"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2016-05-17"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2016-05-18"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2016-05-19"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2016-05-20"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2016-05-21"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2016-05-22"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><thead><tr><td class="fc-week-number" style="width: 18px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span>20</span></td><td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2016-05-16">16</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2016-05-17">17</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2016-05-18">18</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2016-05-19">19</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2016-05-20">20</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2016-05-21">21</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-future red-day" data-date="2016-05-22">22</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="fc-week-number" style="width:18px"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content"><div class="fc-bg"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-week-number fc-widget-content" style="width: 18px;"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2016-05-23"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2016-05-24"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2016-05-25"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2016-05-26"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2016-05-27"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2016-05-28"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2016-05-29"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><thead><tr><td class="fc-week-number" style="width: 18px;"><span>21</span></td><td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2016-05-23">23</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2016-05-24">24</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2016-05-25">25</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2016-05-26">26</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2016-05-27">27</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2016-05-28">28</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-future red-day" data-date="2016-05-29">29</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="fc-week-number" style="width:18px"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content"><div class="fc-bg"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-week-number fc-widget-content" style="width: 18px;"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2016-05-30"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2016-05-31"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2016-06-01"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2016-06-02"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2016-06-03"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2016-06-04"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2016-06-05"><span class="day-plus-shift">+</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><thead><tr><td class="fc-week-number" style="width: 18px;"><span>22</span></td><td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2016-05-30">30</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2016-05-31">31</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2016-06-01">1</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2016-06-02">2</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2016-06-03">3</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2016-06-04">4</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-other-month fc-future red-day" data-date="2016-06-05">5</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="fc-week-number" style="width:18px"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Everything is wrong with your `XPath` :)) You should use relative `XPath` instead of absolute. Provide `html` code sample for target element

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Andersson. I'll add that I'm new to automated tests, webdriver and html code in general. The html code for the element is very long, and I don't know how to copy it all into here. I'll check out the difference between relative and absolute xpath and see what I can learn.

Comment: You don't need full page `HTML` code, just for a table that contains element with required value (code for `div[@class='fc-content-skeleton']` with its child table)

Comment: To get `HTML` (in `Firefox`): rightclick on element -> "Inspect element" -> Select code sample lines -> CTRL+C

Comment: I'm using Chrome on a macbook, and copying one line with CMD+C gave me a lot more than just one line. I tried instead coping in "outer html" where it seems like the full calendar code starts, but the format got borked.

Comment: It's quite hard to read provided `html` code sample. Could you try to show more structured code? Also check whether element you find with `XPath` is really clickable (if no exceptions, like `ElementNotFound`, occurs then `XPath` could be correct, but you confuse target element with something else)

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium WebDriver DatePicker Calendar (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkjSt9cy_kY)

or

[How to handle Calendar in Selenium Webdriver](http://learn-automation.com/handle-calender-in-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: This is good but it seems to handle datepickers rather than full calendar, so it doesn't help me i'm afraid.

Comment: use the same logic! get the month, days in generic lists compare it to what you need click on it and so on ...

Comment: When I navigate to my page, the page loads with the full calendar already open, showing current month. In my test case I want to always double click on the first day (Monday for me) on the third row. The test case won't know what date or month or year it is. Can I still use that logic as in your links then?

Comment: what if driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@class='fc-content-skeleton']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")).Click();

Comment: Clicking on an empty day in my calendar does nothing, it has to be double click. I tried doing this as you can see in the code in my post, but it's not working since my xpath code is wrong. I think the key is to get it right, and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the html is fairly well structured, and that there are useful styles that we can take advantage of. I've confirmed that the following CSS locator/selector will uniquely identify the first day of the "third row" (which I'm assuming you mean to mean the third week).

```
div.fc-row.fc-week:nth-of-type(3) td.fc-day:nth-of-type(2)
```

That's just the column in the table.  do you need to actually double click on the span with the +?  add that span to the locator:

```
div.fc-row.fc-week:nth-of-type(3) td.fc-day:nth-of-type(2) span.day-plus-shift
```

I'm more familiar with CSS paths, so I'll leave it to you to translate this to xpath if you want that.

Note, the HTML is just a snippet.  Please make sure that it isn't wrapped inside of an iframe.  In that case you'll need to switch to the frame first.